# Force dplyr not to drop attributes - is it possible?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the simple example:

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(   a = 1,   b = 2 )

attr(dat, "myattr") <- "xyz"

dat %>% mutate(c = 3) %>% str()
## 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ a: num 1
##  $ b: num 2
##  $ c: num 3
```

So `dplyr` drops the attribute. Is it possible to force it *not* to drop it?

More general: is it possible to force R not to drop attributes when changing object class?

Comment: For reference, the issue you posted: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1984